# Unanswered questions section for Android tag became semi-transparent

Tags: support, questions, user-interface

I don't know either it is a bug or SO is changing design, couple hours ago this happened and it is not fixed yet:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is **not** a bug, this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Any post with a tag you added to your ignored list is displayed with a fade. Since the only tag in common between all those posts is [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) you must've added that tag to your ignored list.

Hover over the tag, and click on the little red `x` mark to *un*-ignore it:

[image: android ignored]

There *does* appear to be a bug with the fading and highlighting *logic*. If you have [foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo) added to your favourites or ignored tags, it should not be highlighted or faded *on the [foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo) tag pages*.  This just *did not happen* for me, I saw the whole `android` tag page as faded too, even though that is not supposed to happen. I suspect [a loading bug I reported before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237250/new-keyboard-shortcut-integration-problems) is at play here.

Comment: I have it ignored, I don't see the fade.

Comment: @HansPassant: There is a per-user preference to *remove* posts with ignored tags from the page altogether; perhaps you have that checked? I do see the fade, for what it is worth.

Comment: Omg, thanks. I know ignored tags are fade but I didn't put Android to ignored tags category, it is in my favs. I checked now and it was there. I guess I clicked by mistake.

Comment: @HansPassant: hmm, it is on-again, off-again. Looks like a race condition between the fader and the detection what tag you are looking at.